# Add column counting repetitions of a sequence

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to add a column to a data frame that counts how many times a sequence has been run through--in this case, months that go up to 12.

I started with month and year, but for my analysis I need to use an adjusted `month_lag` column.

```
year.reprex <- rep(1982:2015, each=12)
month.reprex <- rep(1:12, times=34)
df <- cbind(year.reprex, month.reprex) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(
    month_lag = ifelse(month.reprex < 12, month.reprex+1, 1))
```

I want to add a column with a numeric counter for how many times month_lag has run up to 12. The first value of month_lag is 2, so I can't just count the number of sequences of 1:12. This counter will be offset from the actual year column by one month. In this reprex, for the first eleven rows (month_lag goes from 2 to 12), I want the year_counter to be 1. When month_lag resets to 1 in row 12, the year_counter should increase to 2, and continue ticking up every time month_lag runs up to 12 and starts over at 1. A dplyr solution would be great if possible.

Comment: Yes!! I actually needed `month_lag==1` in your code, so the `year_lag` ticks up when `month_lag` hits 1 instead of 12--but this solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can increment a counter whenever `month_lag` is 1 which can be achieved using `cumsum`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(year_lag = cumsum(month_lag == 1) + 1)

# year.reprex month.reprex month_lag   year_lag
#         <int>        <int>     <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1        1982            1         2        1
# 2        1982            2         3        1
# 3        1982            3         4        1
# 4        1982            4         5        1
# 5        1982            5         6        1
# 6        1982            6         7        1
# 7        1982            7         8        1
#....
```

Or in base R

```
df$year_lag <- cumsum(df$month_lag == 1) + 1
```